# docker run command fails

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to run a container as daemon as follows :

```
$docker run --privileged --net=host -d d34f188005c4
34045723709f3553533a1c823800697e55d43a7e676499310751f7116d3a1068
$docker ps
CONTAINER ID      IMAGE    COMMAND     CREATED    STATUS    PORTS        NAMES
```

As seen from above, docker run cmd returns a long string, but it fails to run as seen from the `docker ps` output. Further, I get following from the syslog while the `docker run` cmd as above executes:

```
kernel: [281942.173389] aufs au_opts_verify:1597:dockerd[21361]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
```

Kernel/docker version and other required info is as follows:

```
# docker info
Containers: 3
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 3
Images: 1
Server Version: 17.03.0-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 8
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 977c511eda0925a723debdc94d09459af49d082a
runc version: a01dafd48bc1c7cc12bdb01206f9fea7dd6feb70
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-116-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 15.67 GiB
Name: ubuntu1604
ID: B35S:GX2J:VTYF:HKJ2:KMIP:SU35:YCSV:YHM2:R6L5:K7CW:4ZUV:EYGX
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Can anyone please let me know how to fix this? Can we get any clue from the syslog above? If any other info is required, please let me know.

Adding additional info based on comments below :

```
$docker logs 34045723709f3553533a1c823800697e55d43a7e676499310751f7116d3a1068
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Access to docker on host failed!!`

$ps -aux | grep dockerd
root     21836  0.4  0.2 436168 42920 ?        Ssl  10:39   0:00 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
```

Comment: What about the host machine .. is there any special configuration... does it support virtualization..

Comment: What does `docker logs 34045723709f3553533a1c823800697e55d43a7e676499310751f7116d3a1068` output?

Comment: Note [this information](https://success.docker.com/article/error-dirperm1-breaks) from Docker on the error you saw in syslog.

Comment: @jwodder : i added the info you asked. Though `docker logs 3404...` says it couldn't connect to dockerd (though it is running as shown by ps). Does it provide any clue ?

Comment: @anothermh : i had gone through this link before. Do you think this might be causing the issue above ? If yes, how to fix it.

Comment: @viks No, the syslog error is not related to the problem you're having. Your problem is that Docker isn't installed and running correctly: `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?` I recommend you go through the Docker documentation on how to install Docker and verify it is running correctly. This problem is NOT related to your app; it is related to how you have Docker installed and configured.

Comment: @anothermh : `# systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-09-24 08:54:46 PDT; 1h 44min ago`
.... as shown by cmd above, docker is active and running. Doesn't systemctl status cmd output itself verifies that the docker is running correctly.

Comment: @viks If `docker logs` says `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon` but you believe that Docker is installed and running then your docker environment is either not installed correctly or is misconfigured. If your `docker` commands on the command line don't work then it doesn't matter what `systemctl` says -- docker isn't configured properly!

Comment: @anothermh : The docker logs command shows information logged by a running container. Since the container itself is not running, this might cause it to give the above output. If you still suspect this to be an issue, please let me know what is the way to debug it further.